# Next.js 13 & Go Dockerized App: Server-Side Exception on Login and ECONNREFUSED Error in Docker Environment

Tags: docker, go, next.js, docker-compose, next.js13

I am currently facing a challenge with my Next.js 13 and Golang application which I have dockerized. The issue arises when I try to log into the application.

Using NextJs 13.5.4 and Go 1.21.5. Browser is Firefox.

Firefox shows:

```
Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information).

Digest: 3933982100
```

and Firefox console shows:

```
XHRGET http://127.0.0.1:3000/logout?_rsc=acgkz [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 34ms]

Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.
```

Docker container log:

```
2024-01-08 08:41:03 backend   | 2024/01/08 06:41:03 INFO loaded config file=config/config.dev.json
2024-01-08 08:41:03 backend   | Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
2024-01-08 08:41:04 frontend  |   ▲ Next.js 13.5.4
2024-01-08 08:41:04 frontend  |   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
2024-01-08 08:41:04 frontend  |   - Network:      http://0.0.0.0:3000
2024-01-08 08:41:04 frontend  | 
2024-01-08 08:41:04 frontend  |  ✓ Ready in 63ms
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  | TypeError: fetch failed
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |       at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     errno: -111,
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     syscall: 'connect',
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     address: '127.0.0.1',
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |     port: 8080
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  |   }
2024-01-08 08:42:15 frontend  | }
```

docker compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - social-network

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/backend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - social-network

networks:
        social-network:
```

frontend.dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base
FROM base AS deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app

ENV BUILD_STANDALONE true

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN apk add --no-cache curl
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./_next
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/public ./public

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

backend.dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY backend/go.mod backend/go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY backend/ .
RUN go build -o main ./server.go
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

I have tried checking the network configuration and ensuring that the ports are correctly exposed and mapped. However, the issue persists. Login works without docker. With docker http://127.0.0.1:3000/login and http://127.0.0.1:8080/ are available on browser, frontend loads and backend responds, but doesn't let me connect with backend when trying to login. I can also ping backend from terminal when docker is up and running, it responds:

```
❯ docker exec -it frontend sh
/app $ ping backend
PING backend (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.904 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.203 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=2 ttl=42 time=0.237 ms
```

Login.tsx

```
"use client"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { isPasswordValid, isUsernameOrEmailValid } from "./validation";

export default function Login() {

    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [usernameOrEmailError, setUsernameOrEmailError] = useState('');
    const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter()

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [canSubmit, setCanSubmit] = useState(true);

    async function onSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault()
        setIsLoading(true)
        let canSubmitForm = true;
        try {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const userIdValid = isUsernameOrEmailValid(userId);
            if (!userIdValid) {
                setUsernameOrEmailError("Invalid username");
                setCanSubmit(false);
                canSubmitForm = false;
                return;
            }
            setUsernameOrEmailError("");
            const passwordValid = isPasswordValid(password);
            if (!passwordValid) {
                setPasswordError("Invalid password");
                setCanSubmit(false);
                canSubmitForm = false;
                return;
            }
            setPasswordError("");
            if (canSubmit || canSubmitForm) {
                const formData = {
                    userId,
                    password
                }
                setUserId('');
                setPassword('');

                const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/users/login", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    mode: "cors",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                })
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return response.text().then(errorMessage => {
                        console.error(`Error: ${response.status}`);
                        console.error(errorMessage);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during login:', error);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
            if (canSubmitForm) {
                router.refresh();
            }
        }

    }

    return (<> .... .... .... </>)

}
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this problem or insights into potential misconfigurations in my Docker setup would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your backend code is trying to call `127.0.0.1:8080`; that is, it's trying to make the call into its own container.  You need to use `backend` as a host name in the `await fetch(...)` call, the same way you did with the `ping` call.

Comment: @DavidMaze how do I set await fetch(...) to backend from docker?